# JTable with editable checkbox

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

The below code is one of my project class.It produce a frame with `JTable` when I click find button some data will load to table dynamically.The last column of table must be checkbox with event.
I tried this code for checkbox (took it from another project..its not working)

```
DefaultTableModel   dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data, colName){
         public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
                return (c == 5? Boolean.class : String.class);
            } 
        };
```

**Actual class**

```
public class BookReturnPanel {
    JPanel retunBookPanel;
    JTextField txtRegNo;
    JButton btnFind, btnSave;
JTable retunTable = null;
    public JScrollPane jScrollPane = null;
    private int i;
    static Object[][] data;
    String regNo = null;
    Member member = null;
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    /**
     * Create the panel.
     */
    public BookReturnPanel() {

    }

    public JPanel getRetunBookPanel() {
        if (retunBookPanel == null) {
            retunBookPanel = new JPanel();
            retunBookPanel.setLayout(null);

            model.addColumn("Member");
            model.addColumn("Book");
            model.addColumn("Issue Date");
            model.addColumn("Return Date");
            model.addColumn("Return");

            retunTable=new JTable(model);
            retunTable.setLocation(new Point(0,60));
            retunTable.setSize(new Dimension(517, 386));

            JLabel lblRegNo = new JLabel("Member Reg No:");
            lblRegNo.setBounds(24, 40, 108, 14);
            retunBookPanel.add(lblRegNo);
            retunBookPanel.add(getJScrollPane(),  BorderLayout.CENTER);
            txtRegNo = new JTextField();
            txtRegNo.setBounds(129, 37, 200, 20);
            retunBookPanel.add(txtRegNo);
            txtRegNo.setColumns(10);

            btnFind = new JButton("Find");
            btnFind.setBounds(359, 36, 91, 23);
            btnFind.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    if (model.getRowCount() > 0) {
                        for (int i = model.getRowCount() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
                            model.removeRow(i);
                        }
                    }

                    regNo = txtRegNo.getText();
                    member = ServiceFactory.getMemberServiceImpl().findByregNo(regNo);


                    List<Issue> issues = ServiceFactory.getIssueServiceImpl()
                            .FindAllIssueByMemberId(member.getSerialNo());



                    for(Issue issue:issues){
                        Vector<Object>row=new Vector<Object>();

                        row.addElement( issue.getMemberId().getName());
                        row.addElement( issue.getBookId().getName());
                        row.addElement( issue.getIssueDate());
                        row.addElement( issue.getReturnDate());
                        row.addElement(issue.getStatus());

                        model.addRow(row);

                    }


                }
            });
            retunBookPanel.add(btnFind);

            btnSave = new JButton("Save");
            btnSave.setBounds(425, 448, 91, 23);
            retunBookPanel.add(btnSave);

        }
        return retunBookPanel;

    }

    private JScrollPane getJScrollPane() {

        if (jScrollPane == null) {
            jScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
            jScrollPane.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 60, 517, 386));


            jScrollPane.setViewportView(retunTable);
        }
        return jScrollPane;
    }
}
```

The above code produce `JTable` perfectly but I need to show `JCheckbox` at the last column.
also it need to add event when a checkbox is clicked..!

Answer (score 2):

1) `JTable` columns indexes starts from 0, if you want to set `JCheckBox` to last column, you need to use index 4 , not 5 as in your code.

2)For adding action to your `JCheckBox` column you can use `DefaultCellEditor` with `JCheckBox`, for example:

```
JCheckBox chb = new JCheckBox();
chb.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            System.out.println("action");
    }
});
DefaultCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor(chb) {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table,Object value, boolean isSelected, int row,int column) {
           Component tableCellEditorComponent = super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);
           ((JCheckBox)tableCellEditorComponent).setHorizontalAlignment(JCheckBox.CENTER);
           return tableCellEditorComponent;
    }
};
retunTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setCellEditor(editor);
```

Comment: @mKorbel,  What do you mean?

Comment: really that code confused me, but I only show to OP how use `JCheckBox` inside `JTable`

Comment: +1 for catching the off-by-one column number; no ned for a new `CellEditor`; the default should use a `JCheckBox` for `Boolean.class`.

Answer (score 1):

@user3318622 : You need to use `TableCellEditor` and `TableCellRenderer` if you want to display checkbox in the last column cell and in the `TableCellEditor` you need to handle `ItemListener` for checkbox.